# Efficiency of two estimators for a sample from a Bernoulli population

Tags: variance, bernoulli-distribution, point-estimation

Given a Bernoulli population, I have two estimators for a random sample of size $n$:

$T_1=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^n X_i + 2X_n}{n+2}$

$T_2=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2} X_i + 2X_n}{n+2}$

I want to compare them in terms of their relative efficiency.

I know that:

$VAR[T_2]=VAR\bigg[\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-2} X_i + 2X_{n}}{n+2}\bigg] \\ =\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}.\{VAR[X_1+X_2+...+X_{n-2}]+VAR[2X_n]\}$

however I am not sure how to continue... the variance of a Bernoulli is $p.q$, should I replace each $X_i$ with $p.q$?

The same for the estimator $T_1$:

$VAR[T_1]=VAR\bigg[\frac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} X_i + 2X_n}{n+2}\bigg] \\ =\frac{1}{(n+2)^2}.\{VAR[X_1+X_2+...+X_n+2X_n]\}$

How should I calculate its variance?

Comment: Are you sure you have stated your estimators correctly?  They look very strange and they do not have the same expected value (only the first is unbiased for an IID sample).

Comment: The variance of the sum of Independent random variables is the sum of the variances... That should get you further!

Comment: Yes, they are correctly stated. How can I show that $T_1$ is unbiased, and $T_2$ is not? The goal is then to show that they both are consistent in mean square $(n \to \infty)$.

Comment: As always, you examine bias by taking expectations.  That's such an easy calculation in this problem that you should be able just to *look* at the expressions and know which is biased and by how much.

Comment: How would you simplify each of the expressions?

Comment: Not to spoil your chance to figure out on your own how to get means and variances for the two estimators, here is a simulation in R with approximate answers: Let $n=4, p=0.4.$ To simulate use R code: `set.seed(2021); n = 4; m=10^6;`
`x1 = rbinom(m,1,.4);  x2 = rbinom(m,1,.4);`
`x3 = rbinom(m,1,.4); x4 = rbinom(m,1,.4);`
`t1 = (x1+x2+x3+x4 + 2*x4)/(n+2);`
`t2 = (x1+x2 + 2*x4)/(n+2)`  Then summarize with code `mean(t1); var(t1); mean(t2); var(t2)` to get $0.3997468, 0.0799563$ and $0.2665365, 0.03995781,$ respectively.. Round to about three places.

Comment: I wouldn't simplify either expression.  With $T_1$ it suffices to count how many of the $X_i$ appear ($n+2,$ obviously) and to note what their coefficients are (equally obviously, $1/(n+2)$ *before* any simplification.) Apply linearity of expectation.  The same approach makes fast work of the expectation of $T_2.$ For the variances it's a bit more trouble but the same approach works well: identify which products and squares of random variables appear in $T_i^2$ and with what coefficients, and again apply linearity of expectation.

Comment: The book where I found the exercise provided the following simplification for $T_2$:

$= \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}.[(n+2).pq+4pq]$

$= \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}.(n+2).pq$

$= \frac{pq}{n+2}$ however I do not follow these three steps.

The same applies for $T_1$ simplication:

$= \frac{1}{(n+2)^2}.VAR[X_1 + X_2 + ... + X_{n-1} + 3X_n]$

$= \frac{n+8}{(n+2)^2}.pq$; I do not understand these steps. I get that $...X_n + 2X_n$ is equivalent to $...+X_{n-1} + 3X_n$, but from that to $= \frac{n+8}{(n+2)^2}.pq$ I do not follow.